# Problem with unit or decimals when tracking token value with "getAmountsOut" on BSC and pancakswap router?

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, web3py

I have a problem when I want to retrieve a token value per BUSD or another token. It may work when I put a >1BUSD token but when I try with a <1BUSD token (like DOGECOIN for example) the amount out is not good, I tried many "toWei" "fromWei" or "10 ** decimals" modifications, but nothing return me a good result. I don't know where my problem is

```
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org:443'))

#0xbA2aE424d960c26247Dd6c32edC70B295c744C43 (DOGE)

def get_token_swap_price(token):

    pancakeSwap_router = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeSwap_contract_ROUTERV2, abi=pcs_swap_abi)

    amountIn = web3.toWei(1,"ether")#######?????

    amountOut = None  
    amountOut = pancakeSwap_router.functions.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [token, BUSD]).call() #######?????
    amountOut = web3.fromwei(amountOut[1],"ether") #######?????

    print(amountOut)
```

abi i used for:

```
[
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "_factory",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "_WETH",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "WETH",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "tokenA",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "tokenB",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountADesired",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountBDesired",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountAMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountBMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "addLiquidity",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountA",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountB",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "liquidity",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "token",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountTokenDesired",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountTokenMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountETHMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "addLiquidityETH",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountToken",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountETH",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "liquidity",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "factory",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountOut",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "reserveIn",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "reserveOut",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "getAmountIn",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountIn",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "pure",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountIn",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "reserveIn",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "reserveOut",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "getAmountOut",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountOut",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "pure",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountOut",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address[]",
                "name": "path",
                "type": "address[]"
            }
        ],
        "name": "getAmountsIn",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256[]",
                "name": "amounts",
                "type": "uint256[]"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountIn",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address[]",
                "name": "path",
                "type": "address[]"
            }
        ],
        "name": "getAmountsOut",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256[]",
                "name": "amounts",
                "type": "uint256[]"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountA",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "reserveA",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "reserveB",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "quote",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountB",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "pure",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "tokenA",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "tokenB",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "liquidity",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountAMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountBMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "removeLiquidity",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountA",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountB",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "token",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "liquidity",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountTokenMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountETHMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "removeLiquidityETH",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountToken",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountETH",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "token",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "liquidity",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountTokenMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountETHMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountETH",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "token",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "liquidity",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountTokenMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountETHMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "approveMax",
                "type": "bool"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint8",
                "name": "v",
                "type": "uint8"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bytes32",
                "name": "r",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bytes32",
                "name": "s",
                "type": "bytes32"
            }
        ],
        "name": "removeLiquidityETHWithPermit",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountToken",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountETH",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "token",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "liquidity",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountTokenMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountETHMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "approveMax",
                "type": "bool"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint8",
                "name": "v",
                "type": "uint8"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bytes32",
                "name": "r",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bytes32",
                "name": "s",
                "type": "bytes32"
            }
        ],
        "name": "removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountETH",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "tokenA",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "tokenB",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "liquidity",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountAMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountBMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "approveMax",
                "type": "bool"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint8",
                "name": "v",
                "type": "uint8"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bytes32",
                "name": "r",
                "type": "bytes32"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bytes32",
                "name": "s",
                "type": "bytes32"
            }
        ],
        "name": "removeLiquidityWithPermit",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountA",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountB",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountOut",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address[]",
                "name": "path",
                "type": "address[]"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "swapETHForExactTokens",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256[]",
                "name": "amounts",
                "type": "uint256[]"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountOutMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address[]",
                "name": "path",
                "type": "address[]"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "swapExactETHForTokens",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256[]",
                "name": "amounts",
                "type": "uint256[]"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountOutMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address[]",
                "name": "path",
                "type": "address[]"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountIn",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountOutMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address[]",
                "name": "path",
                "type": "address[]"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "swapExactTokensForETH",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256[]",
                "name": "amounts",
                "type": "uint256[]"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountIn",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountOutMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address[]",
                "name": "path",
                "type": "address[]"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountIn",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountOutMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address[]",
                "name": "path",
                "type": "address[]"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "swapExactTokensForTokens",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256[]",
                "name": "amounts",
                "type": "uint256[]"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountIn",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountOutMin",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address[]",
                "name": "path",
                "type": "address[]"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountOut",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountInMax",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address[]",
                "name": "path",
                "type": "address[]"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "swapTokensForExactETH",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256[]",
                "name": "amounts",
                "type": "uint256[]"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountOut",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amountInMax",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address[]",
                "name": "path",
                "type": "address[]"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "deadline",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "swapTokensForExactTokens",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256[]",
                "name": "amounts",
                "type": "uint256[]"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "receive"
    }
]
```

For information, i succesfully get the price with reserves, but i really want to succeed with swap function.